# How to take only latest uniq record based on any column

Tags: perl, sorting, uniq

I am writing a script in perl. but got stuck in one part. Below is the sample of my csv files.

```
"MP","918120197922","20150806125001","prepaid","prepaid","3G","2G"
"GJ","919904303790","20150806125002","prepaid","prepaid","2G","3G"
"MH","919921990805","20150806125003","prepaid","prepaid","2G"
"MP","918120197922","20150806125004","prepaid","prepaid","2G"
"MUM","919904303790","20150806125005","prepaid","prepaid","2G","3G"
"MUM","918652624178","20150806125005","","prepaid","","2G","NEW"
"MP","918120197922","20150806125005","prepaid","prepaid","2G","3G"
```

Now I need to take unique records on the basis of 2nd column (i.e. mobile numbers ) but considering only the latest value of 3rd column (ie timestamp)
eg: for mobile number "918120197922".

```
"MP","918120197922","20150806125001","prepaid","prepaid","3G","2G"
"MP","918120197922","20150806125004","prepaid","prepaid","2G"
"MP","918120197922","20150806125005","prepaid","prepaid","2G","3G"
```

it should select the 3rd record as it has the latest value of timestamp (20150806125005). Please help.

Additional Info:
Sorry for inconsistency in data..I have rectified it now. 
Yes data is in order which means latest timestamp will appear in the latest rows.
One more thing that my file has the size of more than 1 gb so is there any way to efficiently do this? Will awk work faster than perl in this case. Please help?

Comment: If you did anything to achieve this. Please show us.That will be great.

Comment: Is your file ordered? Are the latest timestamps always below more recent ones?

Comment: I don't see three `MP` records for mobile number `918120197922` in your example data. Your wording is inconsistent and contradict provided data. Please provide consistent [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text::CSV) to process CSV files.

Hash the lines by the 2nd column, only keep the most recent one in the hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new() or die 'Text::CSV'->error_diag;

my %hash;
open my $CSV, '<', '1.csv' or die $!;

while (my $row = $csv->getline($CSV)) {
    my ($number, $timestamp) = @$row[1, 2];

    # Store the row if the timestamp is more recent than the stored one.
    $hash{$number} = $row if $timestamp gt ($hash{$number}[2] || q());
}

$csv->eol("\n");
$csv->always_quote(1);
open my $OUT, '>', 'uniq.csv' or die $!;
for my $row (values %hash) {
    $csv->print($OUT, $row);
}
close $OUT or die $!;
```

Comment: thanks. It is working but my size of my file is 1 gb so its taking too much time to process. is there any alternate way.. even shell or awk can be  used. please  suggest..

Answer (score 0):

If you know your data is ordered by timestamp you can exploit this and read them backwards and transform your task into a problem to output the first occurrence of each phone number.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS;

use constant PHONENUM_FIELD => 1;

my $filename = shift;
die "Usage: $0 <filename>\n" unless defined $filename;

open my $in, '-|', 'tac', $filename;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ } );
my %seen;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($in) ) {
    $csv->print( *STDOUT, $row ) unless $seen{ $row->[PHONENUM_FIELD] }++;
}
```

If you would like to have output in same order as input you can write into `tac` as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS;

use constant PHONENUM_FIELD => 1;

my $filename = shift;
die "Usage: $0 <filename>\n" unless defined $filename;

open my $in, '-|', 'tac', $filename;
open my $out, '|-', 'tac';

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1, eol => $/ } );
my %seen;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($in) ) {
    $csv->print( $out, $row ) unless $seen{ $row->[PHONENUM_FIELD] }++;
}
```

1GB should not be a problem at any decent HW. On my old notebook, it took 2m3.393s for processing 29360128 rows and 1.8GB. It is more than 230krows/s but YMMV. Add `always_quote => 1` to `$csv` constructor parameters if you are interested to gain quoted all values at the output.